# Page execution being killed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using this code (in combination with my own):

https://www.sbloggers.com/add-a-woocommerce-product-using-custom-php-code-programmatically

This code works as expected, however I have a product with a lot of variations, and the process is being stopped for some reason.

I have:

1. Set max_execution time to 600
2. Issued set_time_limit(0); at the top of the script.

I am only allowing one product at the moment to be written, which has 157 variations based on one attribute. It is writing the product to the database, but sometimes it writes 19 variations, sometimes it's 27, sometimes it's 80. The script is being killed off at random times.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what else to try to prevent it from being killed off? I want the script to just run to completion.

Thank you in advance for your ideas / solutions / thoughts.

The code I am using that writes the variations is below. It is working, but the Wordpress page finishes loading before this routine finishes. It's being stopped at random times.

===================================

```
//Loop and create the variations now based on the product.
            if($variations){

                echo '<p style="margin-bottom:15px;">Variations exist. Variation building...<br /></p>';

                try{
                    foreach($variations as $variation){
                        $objVariation = new WC_Product_Variation();
                        $objVariation->set_price($variation["price"]);
                        $objVariation->set_regular_price($variation["regular_price"]);
                        $objVariation->set_parent_id($product_id);
                        if(isset($variation["sku"]) && $variation["sku"]){
                            $objVariation->set_sku($variation["sku"]);
                        }
                        $objVariation->set_manage_stock($variation["manage_stock"]);
                        //$objVariation->set_stock_quantity($variation["stock_quantity"]);
                        $objVariation->set_stock_quantity('1000');
                        $objVariation->set_stock_status('instock'); // in stock or out of stock value
                        $var_attributes = array();
                        foreach($variation["attributes"] as $vattribute){
                            $taxonomy = "pa_".wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name(stripslashes($vattribute["name"])); // name of variant attribute should be same as the name used for creating product attributes
                            $attr_val_slug =  wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name(stripslashes($vattribute["option"]));
                            $var_attributes[$taxonomy]=$attr_val_slug;
                            echo '<p>Option written: ' . $vattribute["option"] . '</p>';
                        }
                        $objVariation->set_attributes($var_attributes);
                        $objVariation->save();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    // handle exception here
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show us the full script? Could be any number of reasons. Do you have any errors you can share?

Comment: Maybe execute the script separately as described [here](http://symcbean.blogspot.com/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html)